# TFS 2015 build task - Manual Intervention

Tags: deployment, build, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task

TFS 2015 does not have a manual intervention build task. I know TFS 17 does but we are not on this. Does anybody have a workaround for this?

Im looking for a powershell script that I can upload as a tfs 2015 build task and use. I would like to run a TFS 2015 Release and I would like the task to essentially halt the Release process and then continue after some external approval process or something.

This maybe stupid but ... I was thinking maybe something like, you run your Release build, the task opens up a popup window and waits for the user to click "OK" and then continues. I know in practice this is difficult because powershell doesn't let you open a popup window remotely

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual Intervention Task is the new feature in TFS 2017. The workaround for TFS 2015 is to split the workflow into two environments with an approval in between.

[image]

Comment: thats great. Thank you. Sorry I dont have enough rep to mak up your answer.